# How do I convert this data into a DiffEQ to predict values?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently asked "Why do you need to solve a DiffEq?"  The topic was closed since too general, so I am opening with a specific question!

To recap, the answer given:  Say you had data for some variable as it changes in time, if you wanted to predict what the value would be in the future your best bet would be to estimate the derivative and solve the differential equations.

Personally, when I use existing data points to estimate unknown ones, I tend to use scatter plots, correlation, and a regression equation.

I'm not seeing how this translates into DiffEq's.  Well, nothing illustrates/reinforces a concept better than a concrete example. Can we work through a simple contrived example? How about a situation modelling age vs. salary? Here are some data points: (age,salary in thousands) (20,30) (25,55) (30,225) (35,75) (40,100) (45, 110) (50,120) (55,130) (60,140)

What do we do next to "estimate the derivative and solve the differential equations."  We can then predict income at age 65? or 43?

Comment: That was a terrible Answer to your earlier Question.  There are related techniques, moving averages, that are used to model and predict a discrete sequence of data.  However differential equations are continuous models, so there's a least a gap between having discrete data and building a continuous model.  How one fills that gap is frequently a matter of knowing a domain-specific mechanism which is believed to determine or influence future data.  This is a topic for which you should really dig up a specific application and study.

Comment: I'm not really sure where to start.  I just want a simplistic example of a) Arriving at some dy/dx = .... and then b) having a reason to then find y=... that satisfies a).

Comment: I wanted to recommend a paperback that I used in an undergraduate numerical methods course, for the portion dealing with numerical solution of ordinary differential equations (and systems).  It had a wonderful variety of examples, and since it featured software that would solve systems for you, it allowed students to focus on the application, as it seems you'd like to.  If I find it, I'll post a Comment.

Answer (score 1):

As hardmath explains, this example is not very well suited for motivating differential equations.

Here's how I see the lifecycle of a differential equation with perhaps a better example:

1) A physicist studies a natural phenomenon, and concludes that some quantity and its derivatives (rates of change) satisfy a particular relationship.

e.g.: A physicist is studying heat transfer, and observes (via experiment) that his cup of coffee is cooling at a rate proportional to the difference between the current temperature of the coffee and the ambient temperature of the room. She writes down this relationship as

$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = k(T - T_0)
$$

where $T$ is the coffee's temperature (as a function of time $t$), $T_0$ is the temp. of the room, and $k$ is come constant of proportionality.

2) The physicist would now like to predict what the temperature will be in an hour. She consults a mathematician who studies the equation abstractly, and is able to offer guarantees like "a solution to this equation exists" and "given the initial temperature of the coffee, the solution is unique".

3) The physicist and the mathematician now take the problem to an applied mathematician or programmer to actually get a solution. In this case, the equation is simple enough that the applied mathematician can state an exact solution:

$$
T(t) = T_0 + Ce^{kt}
$$

where $C$ is some constant depending on the initial temperature of the coffee. For more complicated differential equations, no exact solution can be written down, and the programmer has to use a computer to compute (approximate) solutions to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting closer.  To recap, Newton's cooling is an example of where you initially determine the function for rate of change (dT/dt=...).  You only know the rate of change as it relates to time.  From there you would want to integrate to get a function for T(t) since this can be used to estimate temp. at any given time.  You start with the rate of change function, and end up with a function for the variable itself.

Comment: Yep, that is a correct summary. In this case, direct integration worked to solve the DE. At this point in your education, you'll soon be learning more methods to directly solve DE's. But just be cautioned that, in general, there aren't always nice solutions like that, and most people using DE's in real-world applications are probably numerically approximating solutions. (but exactly how to do that is something you should learn at a later point in time)